# Upgrade to MacOS Mojave is stuck at calculating

Tags: macos, upgrade, mojave

I am downloading MacOS Mojave. The total size of the download is 6.02GB. Although 6.02GB is downloaded in app store the progress is stuck at calculating.

[image: Download Size]

[image]

Its been two hours like this. Please suggest what to do.

Comment: What is your Internet speed ? Hold Option key and Click on WiFi, read the Tx Rate ? you also need min 8GB of space on your hard drive.

Comment: Looks like there is some issue with the update rollout from apple. Started Mac in safe mode by holding the Shift key after pressing the power button. Downloaded the update and installed in safe mode. 
This fixed the issue.

Comment: Lets make that an answer with how you did it, so others can find it.

Answer (score 2):

Went to Purchased screen.... Clicked on "Pause" while holding down Shift key. It killed the download process. Then went back and Featured and chose "Free upgrade". The process started where it left.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered it too. Could be caused by an interruption in internet connection. I restarted the MacBook after waiting forever. Tried to download again from App store, and it continued from where it got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some issue with the update rollout from apple. Started Mac in safe mode by holding the Shift key after pressing the power button. Downloaded the update and installed in safe mode. This fixed the issue